# What's the point of iOS 6 - (BOOL) shouldAutorotate?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios6

As far as I know the correct practice on iOS 6 is to write a code like this to handle autorotation:

```
// iOS 6
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Instead of writing

```
// pre-iOS 6 support
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    BOOL retVal = UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
    return retVal;
}
```

To be honest, I think that the pre-iOS 6 is much more clear: I don't understand the point of having 2 methods to handle autorotation, specially because I've seen `-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate` returning `YES` in all the examples. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The new API lets you save a call to get the current device orientation: the two questions, namely

- Whether or not the application should auto-rotate, regardless of the new orientation, and
- What are the orientations a device supports

are most often answered statically, without making a call to check the current orientation. The savings become more important when a screen has multiple views controlled by separate view controllers.

Since the iOS is making a call into your app's `shouldAutorotate` in response to an event from the accelerometer, it already knows the new orientation; if your app answers 'YES`, the iOS could then check the current orientation against the list of supported ones, and come up with a decision without your app querying for the current orientation.

In the unlikely case that your app needs to decide on auto-rotation based on the new orientation, the new API is no worse than the old one, so it's a "win-draw" situation.

Comment: it's actually worse. UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape doesn't tell me if the interface in portrait or portrait upside down. And what we have to do now when we need to tell "Yes, rotate but only if you want to rotate to portrait"?
I can't now check 'toInterfaceOrientation' against UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait since it's not present in the new 'shouldAutorotate'.